# how to change set base url to another page

Tags: php

I want to change home URL of my project. I have a project in `localhost/locoff`. when I hit this `localhost/locoff` url it open my `Index.php` file, but I want to open my `login.php` file after hiting this `localhost/locoff` url. how it is possible?

Please help me for this

Comment: paste your login code in index file and change index filename and redirect user after successfull login

Comment: in index.php you can check if there is any logged in user or not. if there is no user logged in you can redirect them to login page using "header" function.

Answer (score -1):

You can add header location on `index.php` file to redirect it to `login.php`.
Ex. in `index.php`:

```
<?php
    header("location:login.php");
```

Comment: before redirecting to login page make sure to check if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: While this technically gives the desired end result, it doesn't actually address the question of how to change the base page of the site.

Comment: Without given answer to any one how I get  reputation? So please do not comment like this, because it discourage to new one